# mysql skipping some update queries

Tags: php, mysql

Like title says. I have an object collection I run through to update some fields. Randomly mysql skip blocks of update queries (no error in logs)... like the first 100 run fine, the next 30 no, the next 250 yes and the last 40 no.

Does anyone has an idea of the issue origin ?

I have a basic mysql server setup (no custom configuration). The table I encounter this issue is a large myIsam table of roughly 3 millions records.

For reference here's what the code (which is definitively not in cause) looks like :

```
$mapping = array('id1'=>'some value', 'id2'=>'some other value');
foreach ($objectCollection as $object) {
    $object->set('field', $mapping[$object->Id()])->update();
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Do you keep opening new connections without closing them?

Comment: Please show us more code. Can't see what is happening from that snippet.

Comment: code and debugging / logging info will be needed. The small snippet shown won't reproduce this kind of problem by itself.

Comment: P.S. Why MyISAM? InnoDB is more robust , and better at doing things like transactions and concurrent updates.

Comment: There's only one connection opened.

It's hard to provide code as it's a custom (but proven) framework.  What I can tell is the generated update query repoopulate all fields and not only the ones changed.

I should add I cannot reproduce it on dev server, so I suspect it has something to do with the server being very busy at the time of the queries (there's a high load on disk, CPU and RAM as it copy and transform hundreds of high definition jpeg).

as for myISAM : cause it was like that when I inherited the application. The engine change of the table is the next thing I plan to try